# Redis node won't go into MASTER mode

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have a simple redis deployment MASTER, SLAVE and 2 SENTINEL running on docker swarm. I run the stack and all services come up. redis-master start as MASTER and I kill it to test SENTINEL and SLAVE recovering. redis-master then recovers and becomes a new SLAVE. If I ecex into it and run SLAVEOF NO ONE the following happens:

```
1:M 31 Oct 2019 06:28:32.741 * MASTER MODE enabled (user request from 'id=3907 addr=127.0.0.1:39302 fd=36 name= age=0 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=34 qbuf-free=32734 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=slaveof')
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.060 * Before turning into a replica, using my master parameters to synthesize a cached master: I may be able to synchronize with the new master with just a partial transfer.
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.060 * REPLICAOF 10.0.21.49:6379 enabled (user request from 'id=1085 addr=10.0.21.54:34360 fd=16 name=sentinel-592f3b97-cmd age=945 idle=0 flags=x db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=3 qbuf=150 qbuf-free=32618 obl=36 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=exec')
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.701 * Connecting to MASTER 10.0.21.49:6379
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.702 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.702 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.702 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.703 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request a056665afb95a1e3a4227ae7fcb1c9b2e2f3b222:244418).
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.703 * Full resync from master: adde2c9daee4fa1e62d3494d74d08dfb7110c798:241829
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.703 * Discarding previously cached master state.
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.715 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 2229 bytes from master
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.715 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Flushing old data
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.715 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Loading DB in memory
1:S 31 Oct 2019 06:28:43.715 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Finished with success
```

MASTER MODE kicks in but then being taken over by REPLICAOF! How can I force redis-master to always be MASTER?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this makes sense.

Sentinel will always remember who joined the master-slave group.

When you manually make the current-slave master, sentinel didn't know if you make this on purpose, or there is a network portion that happened. So sentinels will do a `convert-to-slave` to avoid two masters exist in a group. (aka, [split-brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain_(computing)))

### To remove a node out of the group

Check the [docs](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#removing-the-old-master-or-unreachable-replicas), In short, you need to send `SENTINEL RESET mastername` to **all** sentinels, to let them forget the lost node. Then start the lost node as master, it won't join the sentinel's group.

### To make the previous (failed) master node stay as a master.

After the lost master coming back as a slave, you can do a `SENTINEL failover <master name>`, sentinels will do a failover and switch master and slave. But I don't think you can appoint a master when there are more than 3 nodes.

Comment: OK! Will keep this up for now. Maybe we get another answer :-)